# Django index.html template - menu from queryset

Tags: django

I've got index.html with menu, that is (should be) populated using :

`{% for category in categories %}`

Usually, I can return queryset with categories in my view, but as it is index.html and menu, - am I forced to have that query to get categories, in every single view of my app?
I think it is not the best approach, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use context processor.

```
#app_name_folder/context_processors.py

def get_category_list():
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {'categories': categories}
```

```
#settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                app_name_folder.context_processors.get_category_list
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

After this you can use "categories" variable on all your templates.

```
#temp.html

{% for category in categories %}
```